# redigo connection pool - Why release lock when removing stale connection

Tags: go, redis, connection-pooling, redigo

Redigo is a golang client for the redis database. It uses struct `Pool` to maintain a pool of connections. This struct holds a mutex lock for application putting and getting connection parallelly.

```
type Pool struct {
    // ...
    IdleTimeout time.Duration
    mu     sync.Mutex
    // Stack of idleConn with most recently used at the front.
    idle list.List
}
```

In its `get` method, connection pool removes stale (idle timeout) connections firstly. When finding a stale connection, the pool pops it, releases lock, then closes connection, tries to acquire lock again.

```
func (p *Pool) get() (Conn, error) {
    p.mu.Lock()

    // Prune stale connections.

    if timeout := p.IdleTimeout; timeout > 0 {
        for i, n := 0, p.idle.Len(); i < n; i++ {
            e := p.idle.Back()
            if e == nil {
                break
            }
            ic := e.Value.(idleConn)
                if ic.t.Add(timeout).After(nowFunc()) {
                    break
                }
            p.idle.Remove(e)
            p.release()
            // Why does pool unlock and try to acquire lock again?
            p.mu.Unlock()
            // Close this stale connection.
            ic.c.Close()
            p.mu.Lock()
        }
    }
```

Why does pool unlock and try to acquire lock again, instead of just unlocking before function returns? I guess closing a connection may cost quite a lot time, which will slow down other goroutine waiting on this mutex.

Here is the whole [Pool get method](https://github.com/garyburd/redigo/blob/master/redis/pool.go#L220)

Comment: I think your guess is correct.  Closing a connection can take an unknown amount of time. It seems unwise to lock all use of the pool for this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close a connection may cost quite a lot time, which will slow down other goroutine waiting on this mutex. As what @Cerise Limón said - It seems unwise to lock all use of the pool for this time.

After unlocking the mutex, one of the waiting goroutines gets the mutex. Although goroutine for `get` method still needs to remove stale connections, the one for `put` method can put connection to pool and continue to do other work as soon as possible.

Comment: "Close a connection may cost quite a lot time" --- this needs some elaboration. Under the hood it's implemented as `err := c.fd.Close()`. Under what circumstances can this be slow?

Comment: @zerkms To be honest, I can't understand the underlying `netFD.Close` in net/fd_unix.go. In theory, when tcp terminating normally, each side (client and server) would send FIN and receive ACK from the other. During this time, network latency and packet loss could exist.